# Krita and Kdenlive double icon problem

Tags: gnome, launcher, icons

I have Ubuntu 18.04  Gnome. So, I install Krita (from repo or appimage). Now I open Krita and I see the icon in the "favorites" bar (Dash). I right click it to add to favorites but I have no such option. I close Krita, I go to the Apps and there I can right click adn add to favorites. Now Krita is in the favorites (Dash) bar, but when I click it it opens Krita and another icon appears in the favorite bar. 2 icons. 1 is for the opened Krita and one is the one I added to favorites from the App menu. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lt5X.png

What is happening?

Same thing happens with Kdenlive when I use it as appimage, but not when Installed from repo or flatpak.

How to debug this? How to fix?